# dvc can't pass NSString data in textview in new version of iOS?

Tags: ios, nsstring

```
NSString *str1 = @"offers unique programmes for children aged between 18 months to 6 years in an in an opulent property in the heart of Powai. Our large property has ample outdoor space which makes outdoor learning an integral part of the children's day-to-day curriculum and provides opportunities to engage with the natural environment.";
```

Here data is not passing in new versions of iOS like 9.1

```
dvc.details=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@\n", str1];
```

Comment: What do you mean "don't pass".

Comment: means in textview NSString data r not displayed. example             (NSString *st=@"something";                                                        dvc.details=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@\n", str1];  )

Comment: What is `dvc`? what is `dvc.details`? `dvc` stands for "destinationViewController"? Then it could be helpful to show where you read it. Because I guess that if you log the value just after setting it, it works?

Answer (score 1):

That code isn't legal and won't compile:

```
dvc.details=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\t%@\n\", str1]
                                               ^^
```

You either mean:

```
@"\t%@\n\""
```

or:

```
@"\t%@\n"
```